# Avoiding violation of Reused Abstraction Principle

Tags: .net, dependency-injection

In Dependency Injection we program against an abstraction.

From my experience, I can state that most of the abstractions in an application have a 1:1 relationship with their implementations. This is a violation of **Reused Abstraction Principle**.

Mark Seeman suggested in some of his posts that we can have a Null Object Implementation for the abstractions in order to avoid **RAP** violation ( This suggestion from Mark Seeman could be my inference. Please correct me if I am wrong to quote Mark on this). My question here is.

1. How to do Null Object implementation?
2. Is it ok to violate RAP?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Personally I find it useful to program to an abstraction even if there *is* only one production implementation. In particular:

- Even if you only have one *production* implementation, you may well have other implementations in *tests*, either full-blown fakes or dynamically created mocks
- It's a clearer expression of dependencies than depending on the concrete class in many cases. For example, the concrete class may expose some other public members which you *don't* depend on, for various reasons.

Mind you, this is a false statement to start with:

> In Dependency Injection we program against an abstraction.

You can use dependency injection with concrete classes perfectly easily. There's nothing to say you *have* to create interfaces for your dependencies. Dependency injection is more about how your class *obtains* its dependencies than about what level of abstraction it uses to express them.

So basically:

- Don't underestimate the importance of "test doubles" to implement abstractions, even if you only have one production implementation
- Don't be afraid to depend on the concrete implementation if you really want to, but injecting that dependency is still cleaner than creating it within your class, where it really is a "proper" dependency
- Don't try to inject *everything* - if the behaviour of the dependency isn't really an *interaction* then you may well not want to inject it. For example, don't start injecting "collection providers" just to avoid creating instances of `List<T>` - you don't need to isolate your class from the behaviour of `List<T>` for test purposes, for example.

Comment: Tests! Tests are what make me abstract things out of my classes 98% of the time. And mocks/dummies make sure there are always at least two "implementations". Still feels weird though. I didn't understand your last point about "interactions".. what are interactions and what aren't?

Comment: @stmax: I realize I didn't explain it terribly well - it's hard to put my finger on the difference. If something feels like a *service* of some description (which includes file systems etc) then that feels like an interaction. If it's "just a data container" with no complicated behaviour we need to ignore for testing (e.g. a collection) then there's no need to inject it usually.

Comment: I am accepting this as answer. Comment from stmax completes the answer.

Comment: @RajkumarVasan maybe [this article](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new/) can clear the topic. It uses the terms newables and injectables instead but I think that is what JonSkeet meant.